# Cannot fetch Unity TimeZone from device

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

seems that TimeZone or TimeZoneInfo not working in Unity (2017.1.1f1).
is there any solution how to get device TimeZone?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [System.TimeZone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone(v=vs.110).aspx) Class to get the current timezone of the device

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem with timezoneinfo on Unity3d_5.5.3p1.

When I tried to access timezoneinfo on devices, it always threw the exception. but on editor, it works.

So I tried to make a custom timezoneinfo, but it also didn't work.
(I tried to this way. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.adjustmentrule.createadjustmentrule(v=vs.110).aspx).

Finally I implemented with custom library for timezoneinfo.

http://www.babiej.demon.nl/Tz4Net/main.htm

```
public static DateTime ParseTimestampToPSTDateTime(long timestamp)
{
    TZ4Net.OlsonTimeZone pst = TZ4Net.OlsonTimeZone.GetInstanceFromOlsonName("America/Los_Angeles");

    return pst.ToLocalTime(ParseTimestampToDateTime(timestamp));
}
```

It's easy to use and works!